# Plotting the graphs of many differential equations using JiTCODE in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, differential-equations, jitcode-jitcdde-jitcsde

I would like to plot the graphs of a system of differential equations for individuals connected in a network in Python 3.6. The system of equations is as follows:

```
dx_i/dt = omega_i - mu_i * x_i + epsilon_i * x_i * y_i

dy_i/dt = r_i * y_i - gamma * x_i * y_i + \sum_{j!=1} A_{ji} *y_i


x_i(t) is the antibody response in the i-th individual
y_i(t) is the viral charge in that individual where i = 1,....,n
omega_i is the rate of production and/or transport of antibodies
mu_i is the death rate of antibodies
epsilon_i is the rate of production of antibodies induced by a unit viral 
population
r_i is the intrinsic growth rate of viral population
gamma_i is the rate of destruction of viruses by a unit antibody population
A_{ji} is the ji-th of a matrix representing the strength of transmission from j to i
```

I have written the code for the immune response to viral invasion for *n* individuals connected in a network.

**The model represents a system of coupled equations representing the antibody and viral population in a network of connected individuals.**

```
from jitcode import jitcode, y
import numpy as np
import sympy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import uniform
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


n = 5
alpha = 0.05


beta = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
beta.sort()
mu = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
mu.sort()
epsilon = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
epsilon.sort()
gamma = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
gamma.sort()
omega = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
omega.sort()
r = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
r.sort()


# Knonecker delta

M = np.einsum('ij-> ij',np.eye(n,n))

print(M)

# The transmission matrix A whose elements represent the strength of 
# transmission from j to i depending of spatial factors. 

A = beta * M * sympy.exp(-alpha) 
      
print(A)



def X(i): return y(2*i)
def Y(i): return y(2*i+1)


def f():
    for i in range(n):
    
        coupling_sum = sum(A[i,j]*Y(j) for j in range(n) if j!=i ) 
   
        yield omega[i] - mu[i] * X(i) + epsilon[i] * X(i) * Y(i)
        yield r[i] * Y(i) - gamma[i] * X(i) * Y(i) + coupling_sum
    
    

    
#integrate
#---------------

t = np.linspace(0, 100)
T = np.row_stack([t, t])

initial_state = np.random.random(2*n)

ODE = jitcode(f, n=2*n)
ODE.set_integrator("dopri5", atol=1e-6,rtol=0)
ODE.generate_f_C(simplify=False, do_cse=False, chunk_size=150)
ODE.set_initial_value(initial_state,time=0.0)

#data structure: x[0], w[0], v[0], z[0], ..., x[n], w[n], v[n], z[n]
data = []
data = np.vstack(ODE.integrate(T) for T in range(10, 100, 10))
print(data)


# Plotting the graphs
#-----------------------

plt.show()
plt.savefig('tmp.pdf'); plt.savefig('tmp.png')
plt.title("The Immunoepidemiological model")
plt.plot(t, f)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('f')
fig = plt.figure()
```

I am expecting to get graphs of antibody and viral population over time t. However, i am getting the following error message.

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (1,)

Comment: On top of what Anshul Choudhary correctly answered, you are never using the variable `T` you created, and `plt.show()`  goes at the end.

Comment: In total all the plt commands seem in reversed order. Using actually defined arrays in the plot command, taking the plt commands from back to front should work without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your code is fine except you are not plotting your the correct thing. `f` is an abstract description of your differential equations, not your solution.

Your integrated data is contained in `data` variable, which has the shape (timepoints, system_variables). Now, for instance, if you want to plot the antibody response and viral population as a function of time for the first individual, your plot command should be: `plt.plot(t, data[:,0:2])`.

Moreover, you are not using `t` as the actual times for integration. Following the Jitcode [documentation](https://jitcode.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/), it should be something like:

```
t = np.arrange(0,100,0.1)
data = np.vstack(ODE.integrate(time) for time in t)
```

Comment: @BLESSINGSMUFOYA: If this answer solved your problem, you probably want to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).